# Работа с Backgroundworker и Dispatcher

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mvvm, backgroundworker

Пишу программу на C# с mvvm. У меня есть два эквивалентных куска кода, в которых,по-моему мнению, должна происходить абсолютно одинаковая работа. Суть в чем- постепенная подгрузка(добавление) элементов в коллекцию с помощью BackgroundWorker. Коллекция имеет биндинг с listview  и соответственно  постепенное(пообъектное) добавление в коллекцию отображается в этом listview.
Код:

```
public class ListContactViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
 public ObservableCollection<MessageChild> DialogListFirstPage { get;set;}
 Dispatcher _dispatcher;
  public ListContactViewModel(VkApi vk)
    {  
        _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

       DialogListFirstPage = new ObservableCollection<MessageChild>();
        var bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw1.DoWork += (o, e) =>
        {
            FirstDialogPageMethod(vk); //Создание коллекции диалогов

        };
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();

 //внимания в этом методе достойна только строчка добавления в коллекцию
  private void FirstDialogPageMethod(VkApi vk)
    {
        int totalCount, unreadCount;
        var GetFirstDialigPage = vk.Messages.GetDialogs(20, 0, out totalCount, out unreadCount);


        foreach (var i in GetFirstDialigPage)
        {

            var Names = vk.Users.Get(i.UserId.ToString(), ProfileFields.FirstName);

           _dispatcher.Invoke(()=> DialogListFirstPage.Add(new MessageChild() { AuthorFirstName = Names.FirstName, AuthorLastName = Names.LastName, Body = i.Body, UserId = i.UserId, Date = i.Date, ChatActiveIds = i.ChatActiveIds, Title = i.Title, UsersCount = i.UsersCount, ChatId = i.ChatId }));

        }        
    }
```

на всякий случай приведу строчку биндинга из xaml:

```
 <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding  DialogListFirstPage,Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

И все закономерно: окно открывается пустым и я наблюдаю постоянное добавление элементов в список.

Ситуация 2: Из предыдущего окна я перехожу в следующее , в котором аналогичная ситуация

```
  public class CurrentDialogViewModel:ViewModelBase
  {
   public ObservableCollection<MessageChild> ReadyCollection { get; set; }
   Dispatcher disp;
     public CurrentDialogViewModel(VkApi vk,MessageChild parametr)
   {
       disp = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        ReadyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MessageChild>();
         var bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
       bw2.DoWork += (p, m) =>
       {

           MoreMessages();

       };
       bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
 private void MoreMessages()
   {   
       foreach (var i in builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids))
       {
           disp.Invoke(() => ReadyCollection.Insert(0, i));

       }
       Datas.offset += 200;


   }
```

где **builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids)** возвращает

```
 ObservableCollection<MessageChild>
```

Xaml:

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding  ReadyCollection,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Так вот в этом случае при открытии окна, оно у меня некоторое время остается пустым, после чего список мгновенно отображает все объекты в ReadyCollection. 
От Insert это не зависит, с Add тоже самое. Также это не зависит от **builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids)**, потому что пробовал делать просто инициализацию объекта при добавлении в цикле

```
 ReadyCollection.Add(new MessageChild());
```

Аналогичная история-объекты вываливаются всем скопом по окончании добавления последнего. А я хочу добиться постепенной подгрузки, как в предыдущем окне.
Почему так происходит и что нужно исправить?

UPD: 
Продебажил еще раз - все таки я был не прав и задержка связана с выполнением  метода builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids). И пока он не выполнится весь- foreach не начнется.
Ведь в первом случае я коллекцию заполняю непосредственно в том классе и задержка обоснована работой библиотечных методов перед добавлением.
Во-втором же случае нужно ждать,пока метод выполнится  полностью.

Comment: попробуйте заменить disp.Invoke на disp.BeginInvoke и в цикл после вызова поставьте небольшую задержку потока.

Comment: Да, проделал что вы сказали, желаемый эффект достигнут,но все равно после открытия происходит пауза, секунд 10.
Продебажил еще раз - все таки я был не прав и задержка связана с выполнением  метода builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids). И пока он не выполнится весь- foreach не начнется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В DoWork вместо Dispatcher используйте ReportProgress.
(для его работы надо включить WorkerReportsProgress).

```
partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        this.DataContext = _List = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
    }

    ObservableCollection<Message> _List;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var w = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
        w.DoWork += (s, we) => { 
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                Thread.Sleep(100);   // тут что-то делаем 
                w.ReportProgress(0, i);
            }
        };
        w.ProgressChanged += (s, we) => // выполняется в основном потоке
           _List.Add(new Message() { Text = "t" + we.UserState });
        w.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    class Message {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```