# Как вызывать отображение диалога в новом потоке?

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, события

Имеется класс:

```
  public class ConvertProcess
  {
    public ConvertState State { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

Класс изменяет своё состояние где то в глубине процесса конвертации, зависеть от UI не должен.

Теперь, пишу поверх этого дела форму.
Сделал простой вариант - добавил событие изменения `State` - на нужных мне состояниях добавил `dialog.Show()` и `dialog.Close()` соответственно.

Проблема - т.к. события срабатывают в том же потоке, в котором идёт конвертация, диалог отображается, но отрисовка в нём забинденных свойств не отрабатывает, т.к. поток занят.

Как это правильнее сделать?

ПС: если диалог просто вызвать в новом потоке, то он не виснет, но завершить его привязкой к событию уже нельзя, т.к. нельзя обращаться к WPF в разных потоках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обработчике события вам нужно просто перенаправлять вызов в UI поток c помощью диспетчера:

```
// обработчик события
private void ConvertProcess_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        // мы уже в UI потоке, просто вызываем метод
        StateChanged(e.State);
    }
    else
    {
        // мы не в UI потоке, перенаправляем вызов метода
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(StateChanged, e.State);
    }
}

private void StateChanged(State newState)
{
    ...
}
```

Т.о. процесс конвертации ничего не будет знать о UI и потоках (как и положено), а логика по "маршрутизации" будет находиться на стороне UI.

Comment: уже предлагал такое, но тоже не подходит - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483023/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/483038?noredirect=1#comment558143_483038)

Comment: Именно эвент так завернуть таки не подумал, попробую.

Comment: @Monk _Именно эвент так завернуть таки не подумал, попробую"_         -- я же давал ссылку на [такой способ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480581/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-gui-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A1/480593#480593), а вы сказали: _"А разница в чем? Фактически, снова говорю, выполни вот это в другом потоке, а вот это - в своём"_ -- я так понял, что такой способ вам не подходит.

Comment: @Stack я по ссылке подумал, что речь идёт об Invoke на каждый чих, когда надо обновить форму. А тут явно событие обёрнуто. В любом случае, я пока ещё не проверил, работает ли такой вариант.

Comment: Завелось, но тут есть одна особенность - учитывая, что эвенты срабатывают в разных потоках, брать надо не `Dispather` потока текущего, ибо к нему всегда есть доступ, а `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: @Monk да, вы правы. Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> события срабатывают в том же потоке, в котором идёт конвертация

Чтобы передать данные в основной поток, надо использовать SynchronizationContext

```
using System.Threading;

static void log(string msg) {
   Console.WriteLine(msg + " " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
}

class Convert {
    public event EventHandler Changed = delegate { };
    public void Run() {
        log("1");
        var c = SynchronizationContext.Current; // запомнить основной поток
        new Thread(() => {   // запустить отдельный поток
            log("2");
            c.Send(o => {    // вызвать в основном потоке 
                log("3");
                Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }, null);
        }).Start();
    }
}

var c = new Convert();
c.Changed += (s, e) => log("4");
c.Run()
```

Результат

```
msg  threadId
1    6
2    16     
3    6
4    6
```

---

**Другой способ:**

```
void Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // если метод был вызван из не-UI-потока, то транслируем его в UI-поток
  if(!Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(Changed), sender, e);
    return;
  }
  // выполняется в UI-потоке
  textbox.Text = "hello";
}
```

Comment: В таком случае, процесс конвертации почему то должен подстраиваться под UI и его проблемы(добавлять какую то синхронизацию, делать свой запуск в отдельном потоке зачем-то), тогда как он простой и однопоточный. Мне не нравится идея, что надо менять рабочий процесс конвертации, чтобы можно было его отобразить. Почему я и задаю этот вопрос.

Comment: @Monk _"Мне не нравится идея, что надо менять рабочий процесс конвертации"_ -- есть другой способ. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480581/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-gui-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A1/480593#480593)

Comment: А разница в чем? Фактически, снова говорю, выполни вот это в другом потоке, а вот это - в своём. Т.е. снова процессу конвертации говорю, какие данные мне понадобятся в UI.

Comment: @Monk _"Фактически, снова говорю, выполни вот это в другом потоке, а вот это - в своём"_ -- если хотите чтобы передача данных между потоками была скрыта, то можно использовать BackgroundWorker. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477925/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-backgroundworker-%D0%B8-dispatcher/477965#477965)

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете не совсем верно.

Ваша модель действительно должна/имеет право бежать в любом потоке. Но отображаться должны данные VM, а не модели, а VM должна бежать в UI-потоке. Кроме того, бизнес-логика (а решение начать взаимодействие с пользователем — это именно бизнес-логика) должна происходить на уровне VM, а не модели.

Таким образом, вы должны сделать следующее:

1. Вы заводите VM, соответствующую вашему процессу.
2. Вы заводите экземпляр этой VM в UI-потоке.
3. Вы показываете UI в UI-потоке, привязываясь к данным VM.
4. Вы запускаете модель, которая занимается конвертацией. (VM бежит в своём потоке.)
5. Модель каким-то образом сигнализирует об изменении своих данных. (Любой способ подойдёт: event, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `IProgress`, `IObservable`, что угодно.)
6. VM ловит нотификации, перебрасывает их в UI-поток (любым способом, например через `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` или `SynchronizationContext.Post`) и модифицирует свои данные.
7. UI подхватывает изменения данных и показывает их.

---

Обновление: для вашего случая (в начале работы приложения возможна длительная конвертация) подойдёт такая идея:

Когда приложение стартует, `MainVM` создаёт и запускает `InitializationVM`. `InitializationVM` выясняет у модели, нужна ли конвертация. Если конвертация нужна, она запускается (в другом потоке, но это наверное подробности работы модели), и `InitializationVM` показывает свой UI. Когда конвертация отработала, `InitializationVM` убивает свой UI, сообщает `MainVM`, что она отработала, `MainVM` стартует основную логику приложения (и свой UI).

Если невозможно по каким-то причинам узнать заранее, нужна ли конвертация (хотя в принципе должно быть возможно), есть смысл открывать UI для конвертации только по приходу первого event'а от неё.

---

Когда вы перебрасываете изменение данных в в UI-поток, я бы очень не рекомендовал синхронные, блокирующие функции наподобие `Dispatcher.Invoke` или `SynchronizationContext.Send` — это практически прямой путь к deadlock'ам. Используйте `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` или `SynchronizationContext.Post`.

Comment: А как сделать именно инициализацию ВМ\Формы по событию в модели? Т.е. не держать же мне всю жизнь приложения где то невидимую форму с моделью, которые будут ждать оповещения от модели, только чтобы отобразиться? M - V - VM у меня в целом в голове держится, я именно этот дурацкий кейс не могу понять, как закрывать.

Comment: @Monk: По-всякому. Для начала, VM. VM первична, она существует до модели, запускает модель, и подписывается на её события. Теперь View. Когда вам нужно показать View, вы делаете это либо прямо из VM (простой, но идеологически не вполне чистый путь), либо через отдельный менеджер, который умеет для данной VM создать для неё View (а также уничтожить).

Comment: @Monk: Поскольку VM первична, то жизнь приложения — это и есть жизнь (главной) VM. Именно она создаёт, запускает, останавливает и убивает модели.

Comment: Хорошо, MainVM создаем, запускаем старт приложения. Пока идёт старт, отрисовываем на вьюшке MainVM конвертацию, которая всё равно когда то пойдет? А уже потом, когда инициализация закончилась, просто меняем вьюшку\её содержимое? Фактически, мне теперь надо сплеш-экран какой то, на время загрузки, чтобы пустое окно конвертации не висело все время. Суть ещё в том, что конвертации может и не быть, поэтому я пытаюсь на эвенты повеситься. Ваш ответ сейчас слишком общий, чтобы я понял, что делать.

Comment: @Monk: Когда приложение стартует, MainVM создаёт и запускает ConvertationVM. ConvertationVM запускает конвертацию, и показывает свой UI. Когда конвертация отработала, ConvertationVM убивает свой UI, сообщает MainVM, что она отработала, MainVM стартует основную логику приложения (и свой UI). Как-то так.

Comment: @Monk: Если конвертации может фактически и не быть, есть смысл открывать UI для конвертации только по приходу первого event'а от конвертации. Или явно запрашивать модель о том, нужна ли конвертация, и в зависимости от этого показывать или не показывать UI.

Comment: Во, сейчас логика более менее сложилась. Попробую реализовать, спасибо.

Comment: @Monk: Если конвертации может и не быть, тогда у вас по сути не ConvertationVM, а InitializationVM.

Comment: @Monk: Пожалуйста! Пробуйте!

Comment: @VladD _"SynchronizationContext.Send — это практически прямой путь к deadlock'ам"_ -- есть пример в котором проявляется deadlock? просто Send бывает лучше Post, т.к. если вызывать Post в цикле, то можно очень быстро заполнить очередь на обновление UI, и получается нехорошо.

Comment: @Stack: Разумеется. У меня в практике было много раз. Пример: код из рабочего потока посылает сообщение об изменении, оно доставляется в UI-поток синхронно, присваивается какому-нибудь свойству, на изменении свойства срабатывает бизнес-логика и синхронно запрашивает значение из рабочего потока. Всё умерло. // Поэтому я практически никогда не делаю синхронные вызовы в другой поток. Fire and Forget, только так. Если нужен результат или более серьёзное управление, то `Task`.

Comment: @Stack: Да, чересчур частая доставка данных в UI-поток — плохо. Я предпочитаю Rx/`IObservable`, там можно просто попросить доставлять состояние не очень часто и сразу в нужном потоке: `eventsFromModel.Throttle().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)`.

Comment: @VladD дошел до 6 пункта и понял, что вы предложили тот же в принципе вариант, что и остальные, просто завернули это в VM, которая разбирается с запущенной моделью в отдельном потоке сама, т.е. вьюшка и модель в итоге о потоках ничего не знают. Работает, но решение в итоге не сильно отличается технически.

Comment: @Monk: Мой ответ больше не о технических деталях, а о том, как нужно _думать_, чтобы проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать:

- Создать форму в главном потоке
- По клику на кнопку - запустить нужных механизм конвертации в другом потоке
- Добавить делегат и подписаться на события потока.

Comment: Ситуация такая, что процесс конвертации просто лежит где то внутри `Core.Init()` условного, который надо сделать перед запуском. Т.е. никаких форм нигде нет и "ядро" о них не знает. Соответственно, конвертации по клику тоже нет - само запустится, завершится, и только потом я могу показать основное окно программы. Может что-то плохо описываю =(